# m2doc how to export properties of wordx template

Tags: m2doc

is there a way to export properties of the template given in example in the "In-Flight Entertainment System With M2Doc" project, and import them in my owned wordx document ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No but you can make one using the class [TemplateCustomProperties](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/blob/master/plugins/org.obeonetwork.m2doc/src/org/obeonetwork/m2doc/properties/TemplateCustomProperties.java). You can also open de feature request by opening a new [issue](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/issues).